# What is the correct way to submit content-type header in curl?

Tags: curl, headers, content-type-association

I’m using Mac 10.9.5 with bash shell.  I’m trying to submit a request via curl, but I keep getting errors when I try and set the content-type header.  Below I try

```
davea$ curl -v -o -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username”:”username”,”password”:”password”}’ http://localhost:8080/myproject/login
```

but curl spits back a “curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Content-Type'” error.  Below is the complete output:

```
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for Content-Type:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'Content-Type'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Content-Type'
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#1)
> POST /myproject/login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 40
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 40 out of 40 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B980765C84EA5759F743D1AAE8E189D0; Path=/myproject/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://localhost:8080/myproject/login?error
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 16:03:37 GMT
< 
* Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
```

What is the correct way to submit the content-type header via curl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the correct way to submit the content-type header via `curl`?

Using the `-H` parameter, as you specify:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

On the other hand, you have *also* specified the `-o` (output to file) option, without specifying a file:

> If you want a progress meter for HTTP POST or  PUT  requests,  you  need  to  redirect  the response output to a file, using shell redirect (>), -o [file] or similar.

(from `man curl`)

So the command becomes:

```
$ curl -o output.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"username","password":"password"}' http://localhost:8080/myproject/login
```

*(NB I have also replaced smart quotes in the above command as they have made their way into your question)*

Should submit the header and output (to `output.txt`) as you specify. You could also leave off the `-o output.txt` parameter if you do not require that. Although the `man curl` page doesn't seem to specify it, in testing `-v` cannot be mixed with `-o`.

Comment: Hi, I no longer get that error, but there is nothing in the "output.txt" file.

Comment: @Dave It would appear that `-v` and `-o` cannot be used together; if you want output to file use `-o`; if you want `-v`erbose output use file redirection ( `> output.txt`)